# Incompatibility between WP super cache and PHP APC?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using the "[WP super cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-super-cache/)" WordPress plugin on a Ubuntu 12.04 server and found it is incompatible with php APC.

After installing and activating the WordPress plugin, the blog was down and users were getting a error page:

```
HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfil the request.
```

I noticed a segmentation fault in the Apache error log (`/var/log/apache2/error.log`).

In the troubleshooting section of the WP super cache [FAQ](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-super-cache/faq/) I noticed a description of my problem:

> 1. The "white screen of death" or a blank page when you visit your site is almost always caused by a PHP error but it may also be caused by APC. Disable that PHP extension if you have trouble and replace with eAccelerator or Xcache.

So I commented out the apc Apache extension and restarted Apache:

```
> sudo emacs /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/apc.ini 
;extension=apc.so
> sudo service apache2 restart
```

Sure enough, that fixed the problem - the blog was back up and caching enabled.

The thing is, I actually want APC cache to run as well. The opcode cache is useful. I know I could use another opcode cache but does anyone know a APC setting I can change to allow this plugin to work with APC?

---

Note: I also tried Ubuntu 10.10, 11.04, 11.10 and had exactly the same issue.

Comment: I have been able to run both WP Super Cache and APC in an Nginx environment. Not sure how that would differ from Apache though.

Answer (score 2):

Been looking around for some more technical explanation of this.

I don't believe this problem is Ubuntu related.  I've seen similar Wordpress WSOD crashes... APC, WP Supercache, Apache, FreeBSD.  Site(s) would run reliably for some period of time then WSOD all of a sudden.

Apache restart (which would flush APC cache in memory) fixed the issue.

Turning off SuperCache fixes the issue.

SuperCache probably has some obscure bug with APC...character encoding bug?

Comment: Fore reference, here is a similar question on FreeBSD (with no better answer): http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19963/apc-500-internal-server-error/39515

Also we are running on OSX ourselves and will unfortuntely have to uninstall SuperCache